# Explanation for ? and : operators

Tags: java, string, session, model, if-statement

In my controller class I have the following line of check against my model. Someone please put some light on and explain me that if the model attribute is not null, is it creating a new model attribute

```
Object modelObj=pr.getPortletSession().getAttribute("tickets_from_Model");
TicketModel ticketmodel=modelObj!=null ? (TicketModel)modelObj:new TicketModel();
```

Please explain `?` and `:` in the line

Comment: am i missing something, or is the question missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is turnery operator

```
condition ? if condition is true execute this code : else this code
```

for example:

```
int i = 0;

String str =( i==0 ? "i is equal to zero" : "i is non zero");
```

Comment: Better say *evaluate this expression* than *execute this code*. And the name is *ternary* (since it takes three arguments), not *turnery*.

Answer (score 1):

To be a little clearer, the ? and : are components of the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). When using the ternary operator, you put your condition before the ?, the statement to execute if the condition is true after the ?, and the statement to execute if the condition is false after the ':'. So it acts like:

```
if condition ? then do this : else do this. 
isRunning ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```